# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC on IIS - path issues

Tags: asp.net-core, path, request

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app that I am running on IIS. There is a virtual application in IIS under which the app is deployed.

However despite everything I have tried, I cannot get a path with the virtual application name included in order to include in the `asp-route-returnurl`.

So the URL looks something like this

```
http://servername/virtualappname/asp-net-app-url
```

I tried using context.request.path, host, pathbase, etc. But nothing brings back the virtualappname. I am sure I can get it in javascript with location.href. But how do I fetch that full url in ASP.NET Core. Path and Path base only seem to get me from `/asp-net-app-url` onwards.

I can hardcode it. But wanted to avoid if not necessary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ? If you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we need to know that asp.net core belongs to the application level, and is finally deployed under the main application site, and it cannot directly obtain the path of the child application in the machine level.

If we want to do this, we need to do it with PowerShell or `ServerManager` class.

**1.Query the subsite name by Powershell.**

[image]

**2.Query via code by using ServerManager class**

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

public IActionResult Test1()
{
    var paths = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            Site site = serverManager.Sites["test"];
            if (site != null)
            {
                foreach (Application app in site.Applications)
                {
                    if (app.Path != "/") // Ignore the root application
                    {
                        paths.Add(app.Path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    return Ok(paths);
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason! I was hoping it wouldnt be that much work to retrieve :) Definitely good to know now how to do this. I havent checked if there is a leading slash with the context.request.path that I can trim and if it will route correctly after that without including the child application name. Thanks!